# Calculation of Trimmed Mean in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I try to calculate the Trimmed Mean in Power Bi with the use of a measure called `Thickness`. However I got the error `Wrong Syntax for "Percent"`. Does it have to do taht I use Power Bi in german?

```
Trimmed Mean = 
VAR Percent = 0.5
VAR SortedValues = 
    SORT(
        SUMMARIZE(
            table,
            table[Thickness_mm],
            "Count", COUNT(table[Thickness_mm]),
            "Sum", SUM(table[Thickness_mm]),
            "Min", MIN(table[Thickness_mm]),
            "Max", MAX(table[Thickness_mm])
        ),
       table[Thickness_mm],
        ASC
    )
VAR MinIndex = ROUND(COUNT(table[Thickness_mm]) * Percent, 0)
VAR MaxIndex = ROUND(COUNT(table[Thickness_mm]) * (1 - Percent), 0)
VAR TrimmedSum = SUMX(SortedValues, table[Thickness_mm]) - (SortedValues[MinIndex][table[Thickness_mm]] + SortedValues[MaxIndex][table[Thickness_mm]])
RETURN
    TrimmedSum / (COUNT(table[Thickness_mm]) - 2 * MinIndex)
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: So Germany uses the comma to represent the decimal separator, no? So 0.5 for the UK would be 0,5 for you?

Comment: @JosWoolley It is what I suppose but maybe there should be an error in the code.